# 3V Soft latching switch

Tags: switches, low-power, latching

I apologize if this has been asked before but the answers I found are all over the top for this simple latching application.

I'm looking for a very compact solution:
1) 4.5 volt dc, 3 stacked hearing-aid like batteries.
2) Single 2.xV LED load
3) Push button actuation; push once & release = on; push once again & release = off
4) Soft latching; no power consumption when off.

I'd think something like this should be no more than 4-5 component, not counting the batteries, switch, and led.

A nice to have would be a single chip based solution with (or w/o) switch de-bounce.

I'm somewhat amazed these are not a dime a dozen solutions out there to be found.

Any suggestions?

Much thanks.

**EDIT**
4.5V, 3 stacked hearing aid batteries offers meany more LED options @ ~ 20mA.
http://lednique.com/leds-and-colour/

Hoping to stick with a `soft latch` technology t minimize the switch physical footprint.

A resister and toggle button does not satisfy the requirement.

No programming required preferred.

Comment: Only infrared LEDs are 1.5 V, unless something has changed. You forgot to mention the current required. A part number and datasheet link for the LED would be nice. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Single chip and compact could be: a 6 pins SOT package microprocessor. But that involved coding. Is programming within your scope?

Comment: Why not just a resistor and a toggle button?

Comment: You want what's known as a "press-twice" PB. They contain a mechanical ratchet that's rotated each time the button is pressed. They are used in flashlights, car audio, and elsewhere. Just look around.

Comment: You have required "no power consumption when off". How can that be possible without using a physical toggle switch? You can't keep changing the requirements as people make suggestions. Add **all** of your requirements to the question and **be specific**. What is the exact "switch footprint" that is acceptable to you? What exactly does "soft latch technology" mean to you?

Comment: Not power consumption when off is how soft latch works.

Comment: But what do you mean by "soft latch"? Can you point to an example of this kind of circuit? How do you **know** that is uses **no** (zero, none whatsoever) power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single pole, push-to-on / push-to-off micro switches are readily available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you find a link on something like DigiKey.  Because googling "push-to-on / push-to-off micro switch" returns a bunch of false-positive and ambiguous hits

Comment: "Push Button SPST"?  A SPST as a push button instead of a toggle?

Comment: Hi Steve, Please try 'Push-On Push-Off Micro Switch 18x12 mm'.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.